# Ruby BigDecimal Round: Is this an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bigdecimal, rounding

While writing a test with a value that gets represented as a BigDecimal, I ran into something weird and decided to dig into it. In brief, '0.00009' when rounded to two decimal places is returned as 0.01 instead of 0.00.  Really.  Here's my script/console capture:

```
>> bp = BigDecimal('0.09')
=> #<BigDecimal:210fe08,'0.9E-1',4(8)>
>> bp.round(2,BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_DOWN).to_f
=> 0.09
>> bp = BigDecimal('0.009')
=> #<BigDecimal:210bcf4,'0.9E-2',4(8)>
>> bp.round(2,BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_DOWN).to_f
=> 0.01
>> bp = BigDecimal('0.0009')
=> #<BigDecimal:2107a8c,'0.9E-3',4(12)>
>> bp.round(2,BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_DOWN).to_f
=> 0.0
>> bp = BigDecimal('0.00009')
=> #<BigDecimal:2103428,'0.9E-4',4(12)>
>> bp.round(2,BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_DOWN).to_f
=> 0.01
>> bp = BigDecimal('0.000009')
=> #<BigDecimal:20ff0f8,'0.9E-5',4(12)>
>> bp.round(2,BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_DOWN).to_f
=> 0.0
```

Oh, and I get the same results if I use the default mode, like so:

```
>> bd = BigDecimal('0.00009')
=> #<BigDecimal:2152ed8,'0.9E-4',4(12)>
>> bd.round(2).to_f
=> 0.01
```

Here are my versions:

```
ruby 1.8.6 (2008-03-03 patchlevel 114) [i686-darwin9.2.2]
Rails 2.3.4
```

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: I can't reproduce it in my 1.8.7 environment (ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [x86_64-linux])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, never seen this before, and it definitely looks like a bug. `0.00009` rounded to two decimal places should definitely be `0.00`.

The `ROUND_HALF_DOWN` should not change the behaviour since you're not dealing with midpoint values.

[This link](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=14271&group_id=426&atid=1698) has more details.

It seems to be a bug in the 1.8 levels that's been fixed in 1.9. It's a slightly bizarre one in that it only seems to affect numbers with an even number of zeros before the first non-zero digit and only if that digit is 5 or greater.

That appears to be *exactly* your problem based on the data provided.

Comment: Yep, this appears to be exactly my problem indeed!  Thanks for the sleuthing!

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is a bug too, but what I wonder about is the .to_f to display the result. With BigDecimal you should use .to_s('F') instead since I guess you have a reason for using BigDecimal instead of Floats.